# Assign memory to structure using structure

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Suppose I have the following code:

```
typedef struct _SingleList {
    struct _SingleList *link;
    int data;
} SingleList;


SingleList *prepend(SingleList *list, int data) {
    SingleList a;
    SingleList *newNode = &a; // Note, here I assign memory using structure not malloc.
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->link = list;
    return newNode;
}
```

As, you can see in above prepend function, I assign memory using address of a instead of malloc and it works perfectly, when I call prepend function. Here's a sample:

```
int main(void) {
    SingleList *list = NULL;
    list = prepend(list, 10);
    printf("%d", list->data);

    list = prepend(list, 20);
    printf("\n%d", list->link->data);

    list = prepend(list, 30);
    printf("\n%d", list->link->link->data);

}
```

So, how it works and if it works for others too, then why we use `malloc()` for linked list instead of simply assigning a structure.

Comment: You simply have the impression that this works, but it doesn't. Call a few more functions to trash the stack, print all values, and watch it fall over and die.

Comment: @pmr, you're right. I called it more times. Actually, I called `printf("%d", list->data)` after third call of `prepend`.  and it print in 30, instead of 10.

Comment: I wonder how do you compile it, debug or release? With optimizations it would probably fail sooner. @pmr I think you set a new quality in explaining and depicting UB =).

Comment: As a general rule, you cannot use testing to determine how things work in C: If it doesn't work, you did it wrong. If it seems to work, you most probably still did it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `prepend`, the return value `newNode` is a pointer that points to a local variable `a`. When the function ends, it's undefined behavior to access it. It just **happens** to work in your machine in this simple code, you can't rely on it.

Comment: yes, it doesn't work. I just tested. If I call `printf("%d", list->data)` after the third or fourth call of `prepend` function, it simply print the last call value.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work. If it shows correct values then it is pure coincidence and the memory wasn't overwritten by something else or someone else. When the `prepend()` function exits, memory allocated for the `a` structure is freed. Memory for that structure is only available in local context.